# JavaFx Location is not set when application is compiled to a jar file

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

My program runs fine when I run it on eclipse but when I package it in a jar file, I get this error when I run it.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at controller.MainController.initAnalyzer(MainController.java:144)
        at applicationMain.Main.start(Main.java:32)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am certain that the path is correct. I have tried to change the path but nothing seems to work. I've also checked answers here and from other websites but nothing seems to solve my problem. It just does not make sense that my other FXML files under the same folder loaded well but not these three.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think of the two following ways:

1. Make sure you set the path correctly. Anyway you should show us the folder system and how you set the path. Don't forget that the path starts from the current package, not the root of the project.
2. `Clean and Build` your project and run it again. It often somehow helps me to solve lots of issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. You may see the path from the image I included. I'll try clean build to see if it solves the problem. About the paths, I'm certain they are correct because other FXML files under the same folder are loaded.

Comment: I've fixed it. I deleted the fxml files and wrote new ones identical to them. For some wierd reason, it worked.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes the best way is to go it "again". Glad it works :)